# How to manage the state in Get.bottomSheet? flutter

Tags: flutter, setstate, flutter-getx

i could not manage the state when i used Get.bottomSheet even when i wrap it with GetBuilder(), and use update() function.

here is the code

**this is the function that show the comments in a bottomsheet.**

```
  commentFunction(context, id, comments) {
Get.bottomSheet(CustomPageForComments(
    postid: id,
    sendCommentFunction: () {
      sendComment(id, commentController.text);
    },
    controllerForCommentField: commentController,
    comments: comments));}
```

**the CustomPageForComments() is a simple page that used stream in order to get the comments from database.**

and finally this is the send comment function

```
  sendComment(String id, String message) {
commentController.clear();
DocumentReference setter =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Posts").doc(id);

setter.update({
  "comments": FieldValue.arrayUnion([
    {
      "username": currentusername,
      "message": message,
      "time": DateTime.now(),
      "id": formatDate(DateTime.now(),
          [yyyy, ":", mm, ":", dd, ":", hh, ':', nn, ":", ss]),
    }
  ])
});
update();}
```

i want to refresh the bottom sheet when i use the send comment function, so the user can see his comment without re- opening the bottom sheet.

when you close the bottom sheet and re-open it, it actually update

how can i manage that?

also i wanted to ask, is it true to use stream Builder in comments instead of Future Builder?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

To change the state inside a bottom sheet you can use **StatefulBuilder**

```
Get.bottomSheet(
   StatefulBuilder(
         builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
    return Container(
      height: heightOfModalBottomSheet,
      child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          // Change state here
        });
      }),
    );
  });
)
```

If you want the comments to update in real time (could incur higher costs due to reads) use a **Stream Builder** , to fetch data just once use **FutureBuilder**

Answer (score 0):

All works fine with update() in bottomSheet.
Make sure for proper use GetBuilder. You need refresh inner widget, not the Get.bottomSheet function. Your code should look like this:

```
              Get.bottomSheet(
                GetBuilder<CommentController>(builder: (cLogic) {
                return Text('Comments count: ${cLogic.count}');
              })
             );
```